# How do I create a partitioned table in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Google recently announced [partitioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/03/google-bigquery-cuts-historical-data-storage-cost-in-half-and-accelerates-many-queries-by-10x) in BigQuery which have many advantages.
However, I found no documentation of how to create such tables.
How do I create such a table, either in the UI, the CLI, or the API (java etc.)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [timePartitioning](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#timePartitioning) property of table resources.
You can experiment with it I think :o)
More about it in [Partitioned Tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables) and [Creating and Updating Date-Partitioned Tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#creating_a_partitioned_table)

Comment: Note: you may need to update your cloud sdk shell for it to support the time_partitioning_type parameter

Answer (score 7):

You can run this code in the UI / CLI to create a table with partitioning.

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false '
CREATE TABLE dw_prod.example_table (
    company STRING, 
    value FLOAT64,
    ds DATE)
PARTITION BY ds
OPTIONS(
  expiration_timestamp=TIMESTAMP "2028-01-01 00:00:00 UTC",
  description="Example table create in BQ CLI",
  labels=[("example","summary")]
);'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Instead of just pasting a code block, you should give an explanation of what the code does and how it's relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I did have a hard time finding [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language) so I'm adding it here:

```
{CREATE TABLE | CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS | CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE}
[[project_name.]dataset_name.]table_name
[(
  column_name column_schema[, ...]
)]
[PARTITION BY partition_expression]
[CLUSTER BY clustering_column_list]
[OPTIONS(table_option_list)]
[AS query_statement]
```

Note that you can cluster a table from a view select, which is pretty neat.